# Show maximum and minimum value in a choropleth map legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been making a map in d3 and I managed to add a legend that draws the scale following this example: https://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/27/responsive-legends-with-d3/

My question now is how can I modify it to show minimum and the maximum number, the first and the last on the scale.

I know about d3.max and d3.min, and I've been trying to do it, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the following color ramp:

```
var ramp = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range(["red","blue"]);
```

calling **ramp(0)** will return "#ff0000" (red)

calling **ramp(100)** will return "#0000ff" (blue)

---

You can find the min and max value in the domain by using [d3.extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-arrays#extent).

Calling:

```
d3.extent(ramp.domain())
```

returns:

```
[0, 100]
```

---

In the legend scenario, you will have to generate legend keys only for the min and max values in the range, not for the whole range:

```
var keys = legend.selectAll('li.key').data(d3.extent(colors.range()));
```

---

**Updated Answer**
You have several options, if you want to show the buckets, but only have the first and the last value as labels.

Probably, the easiest one is to use CSS. Make the labels transparent by default:

```
li.key {
    border-top-width: 15px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    color: transparent;
    width: 10%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

and then just show the first and last key:

```
li.key:first-child, li.key:last-child {
    color: black;
}
```

Color transparency will not work in < IE 8

Comment: Thanks! but if you do that the in-between buckets also disappear. What I really wanted to do is to show the buckets, but only have the first and the last value as labels.

Comment: Thanks, is super easy with CSS!